# Why does my QWidget stylesheet not recognise objectName rules?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qtwidgets

Here I have a subclass of QComboBox which is going to change the colour of its text according to the validity of its contents.

```cpp
namespace
{
    const QString GOOD = "good";
    const QString BAD  = "bad";
}

NewDBLabel :: NewDBLabel( DB db, const QString & table ) :
    m_db (db)
{
    connect (this, SIGNAL (textChanged (const QString &)),
            this,  SLOT   (changed     (const QString &)));

    setStyleSheet (
        "QWidget#" + GOOD + " {color: black;} "
        "QWidget#" + BAD  + " {color: darkRed;}");
}
    
void NewDBLabel :: changed (const QString & label)
{
    if (m_db .label_exists (m_table, label))
    {
        qWarning ("exists"); // this is printed correctly
        setObjectName (BAD);
        emit valid (false);
    }
    else
    {
        qWarning ("new"); // this is printed correctly
        setObjectName (GOOD);
        emit valid (true);
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this conforms to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html): `QWidget#foo` should match subclasses of QWidget whose `objectName` is `foo`.

I expected that `setObjectName` would cause the different style rules to be applied, but this doesn't happen. Any idea why?

Comment: It is, in essence, a Qt bug - a missing feature. The widget's event handler gets notified of name changes, and it wouldn't be a problem to set a flag if the stylesheet depends on the name. Since the widgets module is considered feature-complete, to have any chance of fixing it at the level of Qt you'd need to submit the code yourself for review.

Comment: Perhaps you should try a selector based on property values? Maybe the style machinery tracks these? All you want is to dynamically change the applicable style, right? The object name is but one way of doing it.

Answer (score 5):

Syntax is correct, but `stylesheet` is not so dynamic. In your code you `setObjectName()` after setting `stylesheet`, so `objectName` was changed, but `qss` was not re-applied. So try to `unpolish/polish` widget. In this case `qss` will be able to detect new `objectNames` and properties.

For example:

```cpp
//in ctor
ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("QWidget#good {color: green;}"
                              "QWidget#bad  {color: red;}  ");
//in handler
if(ui->pushButton->objectName() == "good")
    ui->pushButton->setObjectName("bad");
else
    ui->pushButton->setObjectName("good");

ui->pushButton->style()->unpolish(ui->pushButton);
ui->pushButton->style()->polish(ui->pushButton);
```

---

However, re-applying a stylesheet should be avoided, because the best and fastest way is to `unpolish/polish` the widget. Moreover, `setStyleSheet()` calls `polish()` and also parses the whole string again, so it is just completely unnecessary step, which only reduces performance.